# React project dependency issue

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, auth0

Have been struggling with dependency issues to no avail. I have built a React app (with typescript). I first added [Auth0 authentication](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-react) which requires React version 16.14.0. This works well despite being a more dated version of React.

Then, I wanted to install [Material UI](https://mui.com/getting-started/installation/), however this requires React >17.0.0. How can I handle these dependency conflicts?

package.json

```
    {
  "name": "23xi-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@auth0/auth0-react": "^1.9.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.3",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.4",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.26",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.43",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.14",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.24",
    "add": "^2.0.6",
    "react": "^17.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: React 17 is listed as a peer dependency in auth0: `"react": "^16.11.0 || ^17",`, so you should be ok with any `"react": "^17.0.2",` that mui requires. Make sure that you specify/install the ***same*** version for both `react` and `react-dom`. Right now you've mixed versions between them.

Comment: Thank you for your help @DrewReese -- this solved it